# word2vecでテキストモードで出力した結果を、binaryモードでの出力結果にPythonで変換したい

Tags: python, c, word2vec, 自然言語処理

word2vecというC言語のプログラムで単語情報を多次元ベクトル化する際に出力されたテキストファイルが手元にあります。
次のコードの`else`の文章で出力されたものです。

```
for (a = 0; a < vocab_size; a++) {
    fprintf(fo, "%s ", vocab[a].word);
    if (binary) for (b = 0; b < layer1_size; b++) fwrite(&syn0[a * layer1_size + b], sizeof(real), 1, fo);
    else for (b = 0; b < layer1_size; b++) fprintf(fo, "%lf ", syn0[a * layer1_size + b]);
    fprintf(fo, "\n");
}
```

[ソース](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/source/browse/trunk/word2vec.c?r=41#562)

`if(binary)`の`else`の方で出力されたベクトルファイルが手元にありますが、その後`if(binary)`の方で出力されたファイルが必要になりました。
ファイルの中身は以下のようになっています。

<単語><スペース><数値><スペース><数値><スペース>

今書いているコードは次のようです。

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import struct
#テキストベクトルデータの読み込み
title = sys.argv[1:]
i = 0
fp = open('binaryVec.bin','wb')
odata = ''

for line in open(title[0]):
    chars = list(map(hex, map(ord, line)))
    print line
    print chars
    odata += struct.pack('s',chars)
fp.write(odata)
fp.close()
```

---

データが大きいため効率のよい変換プログラムがあると良いです。

よろしくお願いします。

文字コードはテキストもpythonプログラムもutf-8を使用しています。
テキストベクトルの一部を載せます。

---

```
多い 0.205392 -0.245325 0.240983 0.533283 0.087030 -0.198588 0.395930 0.331363 -0.212541 0.383991 0.391010 0.140275 0.178444 -0.331018 -0.303288 -0.168199 0.227571 -0.133808 -0.583108 -0.004697 -0.068092 -0.057790 0.199027 -0.443492 0.006436 -0.098054 0.221261 -0.413350 -0.274608 -0.266688 0.198686 -0.347939 -0.272542 -0.005835 0.195161 0.255993 -0.435598 0.083113 -0.061061 -0.602378 0.244479 -0.090220 0.053294 0.225144 0.084010 0.150409 -0.078552 0.184509 0.068329 -0.045706 -0.037543 -0.347720 0.363027 -0.251563 -0.293957 0.201196 -0.062295 -0.102561 -0.093551 -0.212615 -0.000832 -0.071720 -0.404002 0.124075 0.283026 0.108321 -0.177551 -0.681601 0.051641 0.324483 0.078215 -0.282532 0.313095 -0.250052 -0.872598 0.035464 -0.266010 -0.389549 -0.120772 0.243341 -0.255850 0.044791 -0.151454 0.159697 -0.320580 -0.663053 0.167484 0.361221 0.185417 0.342295 0.889678 -0.302563 0.289107 -0.102576 0.263508 -0.012531 0.298031 -0.515175 -0.127688 -0.260832 
可能 0.108951 -0.258674 0.629972 0.311664 -0.077146 -0.124886 -0.096122 0.011065 -0.309206 0.867305 0.633274 0.006818 0.267469 -0.119733 0.521135 -0.064882 -0.018288 -0.010180 -0.729432 -0.028794 -0.299309 -0.141295 0.623287 -0.417451 0.007524 0.092700 0.215297 -0.506577 -0.271396 -0.184997 -0.198890 -0.349385 -0.178141 0.230034 0.141386 0.193577 0.223477 0.341060 -0.165425 -0.397568 0.020117 0.154478 0.313013 0.013119 0.172535 0.277345 -0.347708 0.686350 -0.181311 0.344334 -0.119619 -0.433781 0.426598 -0.588145 -0.155892 0.060375 0.023153 0.062405 0.193624 -0.262037 0.259582 0.140148 -0.697635 -0.071356 0.526129 -0.122136 -0.622095 -0.284502 0.130523 0.427264 0.295688 -0.340023 0.310286 -0.043206 -0.201572 -0.319277 0.377619 0.101276 -0.208789 0.099027 0.056171 -0.081605 -0.523134 0.181316 -0.018701 -0.517925 -0.108934 0.514148 0.504512 0.430822 0.481150 -0.165199 0.472695 0.080885 -0.141376 0.324130 0.128912 -0.219854 -0.160605 -0.224664
```

Comment: 何かで扱えるような形式に変換したいのだと思いますが、どういうテキストのデータを、どういうバイナリのイメージにしたいのでしょうか。テキストデータもテキストのバイナリ情報が入っているのでその意味ではバイナリデータです。

Comment: 最終的な目標が分かりやすいように、タイトルを編集しました。また最初に引用されているコードの文脈が分かりやすいようにword2vecのソースへのリンクを追加しました。今書いているコードで詰まっているのはどこですか? エラー内容やどこを問題と考えているかを共有すると、単に動くプログラム以上に、より助けになる回答がもらえると思います。

Comment: ここはツールの製作依頼をする場ではありません。入力ファイル名を〜とか、入力から出力まで一貫して〜というのは自分で頑張ってみてはどうですか？ また情報の小出しはやめましょう。大分揃っては来ましたが、出力のイメージが示されていないので求めているファイルになるかは判断できません。何かの入力に使いたいのでしょうから、そこが重要になると思いますが、そこは自分で調整できるから問題ないのでしょうか。

Comment: 「入力ファイル名をコマンドラインから与えたい」という問題は、「word2vecのバイナリ形式に変換したい」という問題からはちょっと外れているので、別の質問として投稿した方がよいと思います。別の質問として、詰まっている箇所について詳しく書かれている方が回答しやすいです。

Comment: 了解しました。色々と勉強になります。
不適切な問い方だったと反省しました。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: 自然言語処理をやっているなら、NLTK (Natural Language Toolkit) をみるといいかもしれません。まだ、使っていないのですが、たぶん、やりたいことは、すべてNLTK内ですることは可能じゃないかと思います。

http://www.nltk.org/

Answer (score 5):

Pythonで数値をバイナリに吐き出す方法を2つ説明したいと思います。
まず、何らかの方法でデータを得て、以下のような形でfloatのリストで持っているとします。

```
data = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
```

### struct.pack を使う方法

```
import struct
with open('binaryVec.bin', 'wb') as f:
    for x in data:
        four_bytes = struct.pack('f', x)
        f.write(four_bytes)
```

- [packのformat characterの種類と意味](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters)

### numpy arrray の tofile メソッドを使う方法

上記の方法はforループを使うので、スピードが遅いです。
tofileメッソッドを使うと一気にバイナリファイルに書き出すことができます。

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array(data, dtype='float32')
X.tofile('binaryVec.bin')
```

今の場合、この2つの方法で作られた`binaryVec.bin`ファイルは全く同じものになります。
(32bit floatで保存されている)

---

補足: テキストファイルの読み出しについて

`Vec.txt`が以下のような形式で与えられているとします。(エントリがスペースで区切られている)

```
日本語 0.1 0.2 0.3
```

このファイルをparseする1つの簡単な方法としては、`csv.reader`を使うことです。

```
import csv
with open('Vec.txt', 'rt') as g:
    for row in csv.reader(g, delimiter=' '):  # 入力ファイルは一行しか無いので、これでrowに全データが入る。
        pass
data = map(float, row[1:])  # これで、data = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3] になる。
```

Comment: テキストファイルを読み込む方は、`csv.reader`を`delimiter=' '`オプション付きで使えばいいと思います。

Comment: 上記の手法ではdataのlistに単語（日本語）が含まれていないのですが大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: "バイナリファイルに書き出す話" と "テキストファイルを読み出す話" は無関係だと思ったので、前半では前者のみを解説しました。後者についても追記しました。

Comment: data = [日本語 ,0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
というふうにはできませんか

Comment: 上記のコードで`row==['日本語' ,0.1, 0.2, 0.3]`です。

Comment: @ILoveNLP もし日本語もバイナリファイルに出力したいということであれば、示されているCのコードにも日本語出力部分はありません。私の回答でも書きましたが出力するにしてもテキストファイルのエンコードや出力するときのエンコードが不明ですし、さらに区切りをどうすればいいか示す必要があるかと思います。

Comment: 元のプログラムの出力部分で一部抜けがあったので追加しました。
よろしくお願いします

Comment: @field onion 補足ありがとうございます。ナルホド、理解しました。"日本語"の部分もバイナリに書きだそうとしていたんですね。

Comment: 結局のところ、ifの場合もelseの場合も日本語の部分は`fprintf(fo, "%s ", vocab[a].word);`で書き出しているので、これをPythonでどう真似るかということですよね。

Comment: そうです。そこが上手くできていないところです。

Comment: pythonでstruct.packを使う方法を実行した所
-------
<module>
  f.write(four_bytes)
NameError: name 'four_bytes' is not defined
--------
と表示されました。
上の行で代入しているのに、なぜ、このようなエラーが出るのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

**前半部分** 質問も大分体裁が変わったので前半は削除しました。

---

## 日本語出力部分について追記

文字コードが不明なのでそこは気がかりですが、以下の様にすれば出力できると思います。
ライブラリの利用は @ywat さんが[こちらで](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1591/728)示しておられるので、私はベタな形で。

```
import struct

def write(out_filename, word, float_strings):
    with open(out_filename, "ab") as fp:
        fp.write(word)
        fp.write(struct.pack('b',0x20))
        for x in float_strings:
            fp.write(struct.pack('f', float(x)))
        fp.write(struct.pack('b',0x0a))

def convert(from_filename, to_filename):
    with open(from_filename, "rt") as f:
        with open(to_filename, "wb") as fp:
            # to empty
            pass

        for line in f:
            splited=line.split(" ")
            write(to_filename, splited[0], splited[1:])


if __name__=='__main__':
    convert('sampleIn.txt', 'binaryVec.bin')
```

sampleIn.txtは以下の様なテキストです。

```
データ 1.1 2.2
データ2 1.1 2.2
```

SJISですと以下の様なバイナリになります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 入力ファイルは自然言語処理で言う単語ベクトルを保存しています
ベクトルが入っているテキストファイルは
<単語名(日本語)><スペース> <数値><スペース><数値><スペース>…
と並んでいます

Comment: @ILoveNLP 勘違いしてました。elseブロックは入力ファイルを作るためのものだったということですね。やはり出力のイメージがわかないですね。日本語の文字コードですとか…。入力のテキストと出力のバイナリイメージ（バイナリエディタのスクリーンショットでもかまいません）がないとなんとも…。

Comment: 元のc言語のプログラムのファイル生成部分で重要な部分が抜けていたので追記しました。申し訳ありません。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @ILoveNLP 日本語出力を含めたソースを追加しました。